# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BybitWebsocket'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to connect the Bybit websocket to Python via this code.

```py
    from BybitWebsocket import BybitWebsocket
    ws = BybitWebsocket(wsURL="wss://stream-testnet.bybit.com/realtime",
                    api_key=None, api_secret=None)
    ws.subscribe_instrument_info(symbol="BTCUSD")
    while True:
        data = ws.get_data("instrument_info.100ms.BTCUSD")
        if data:
            print(data)
```

I'm new to Python and websockets so I have no idea why this does not work. I have already pip installed the websocket with the command:
`pip install bybit-ws`. I get the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BybitWebsocket'". It has probably to do something with a path, but I still can't fix it. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

`install bybit-ws` is the correct command to install the module you are looking to import, but to make sure that your module is being installed within the correct Python environment, perform:

```bash
pip3 install bybit-ws
```

And then run your code. You might otherwise be well installing it into the system Python (likely Python2, if you are on OSX).

You can check that the module is importable in **Python3** if you open a Terminal window and type in:

```bash
python3

from BybitWebsocket import BybitWebsocket
```

If the above succeeds, your import **will** work if you run it from the Terminal with:

```
python3 path/to/your/script.py
```

But if you still get the `ModuleNotFound` error when you run it from your IDE, then your IDE is configured to execute code within the wrong environment.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me :(. It gives the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you open the terminal and first type in `python3`, then Enter and then `from BybitWebsocket import BybitWebsocket` ? Do you get the error?